# Is it possible to setBadge without bouncing in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

In the Electron API there is a

- `dock.setBadge` to set dock badge
- `dock.bounce` to start bouncing

`setBadge` also starts bouncing app icon.

Is it possible to `setBadge` without bouncing in Electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reviewing the API, I've found that `window.flashFrame` actually makes the icon bounce.
And `dock.setBadge` only sets badge, without bouncing.

So yes, it is possible with `window.flashFrame`.